# Scrape xhr with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm using UBot to create a bot that scrape pages and I'm trying to learn by scrapping Pinterest, may be not the easiest one, and I'm facing a big issue.
I've scrapped the search people page with success, but scrapping the followers of those profiles is another story. In fact the data is updated with Ajax after every scroll. I want to extract the username in the body response.

screenshot: https://ibb.co/mPUx0w

I'm a beginner in Javascript/jQuery and I don't know where to start. Can you guys tell me what to look for? I can't find the information, I've already succeeded at extracting the header, but unfortunately there was no data in it.

This is the output I want to scrape after each scrool:

> resource_response : {data: [{username: "xxxxxx",
>   last_pin_save_time: "Sun, 26 Mar 2017 17:19:29 +0000",…},…],…} data :
>   [{username: "xxxxxx", last_pin_save_time: "Sun, 26 Mar 2017
>   17:19:29 +0000",…},…] 0 : {username: "xxxxxx",
>   last_pin_save_time: "Sun, 26 Mar 2017 17:19:29 +0000",…} 1 :
>   {username: "xxxxxx", last_pin_save_time: "Thu, 28 Sep 2017
>   00:59:27 +0000",…} 2 : {username: "xxxxxx",
>   last_pin_save_time: "Sun, 11 Jun 2017 19:30:05 +0000",…} 3 :
>   {username: "xxxxxx", last_pin_save_time: "Tue, 31 Jan 2017
>   15:53:28 +0000",…} 4 : {username: "xxxxxx", last_pin_save_time:
>   "Fri, 10 Nov 2017 22:44:21 +0000",…} 5 : {username: "xxxxxx",
>   last_pin_save_time: "Tue, 07 Mar 2017 17:01:23 +0000",…}

Your help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: This the code but it's the ubot visual programming language (made to work only in pages similar to this https://www.pinterest.ca/moderncatmag/followers/)

https://www.pinterest.ca/moderncatmag/followers/%C2%A0

```
 clear list(%searchlistfollowers)
set list position(%searchlist,1)
loop($list total(%searchlist)) {
    navigate("https://www.pinterest.ca{$list item(%searchlist,$list position(%searchlist))}","Wait")
    click(<data-reactid=149>,"Left Click","No")
    loop(20) {
        run javascript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight); 
")
        wait for browser event("Page Loaded","")
        wait(1)
    }
    add list to list(%searchlistfollowers,$scrape attribute(<href=w"/*/">,"href"),"Delete","Global")
    set list position(%searchlist,$add($list position(%searchlist),1))
    wait(3)
}
```

Comment: It seems to be Json. The problem is that I don't have that output. I'm looking for a way to scrape it but I don't know where to start :(

Comment: The code is added to my initial post

Comment: Never mind It was my fault, command outside the loop. What a dump a$$